# React Hook Form defaultValues v/s values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, react-hook-form

When using React Hook Form, while I understand that the "defaultValues" is used to set the form field values on initial form load.

However, let's say there is a dynamic form with dependent fields e.g. if Dropdown Field 1 is set to "ABC", then Field 2 should be set to "ABC 1 Updated"
To handle such use cases, is it possible to "watch" Field 1 and based on it's value, update the "defaultValues" with Field 2 then set to "ABC 1 Updated"

or is it not recommended to update "defaultValues" after the initial form load.

I also see "values" in the below documentation, but haven't seen it's usage much. Other option is doing "setValue". Not sure what is the recommended way of handling side effects with a dynamic form with dependent fields.

https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform#defaultValues

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's not recommended to update "defaultValues".

You can use [reset](https://Reset%20the%20entire%20form%20state,%20fields%20reference,%20and%20subscriptions.%20There%20are%20optional%20arguments%20and%20will%20allow%20partial%20form%20state%20reset.) or setValue

Answer (score 0):

You should use `values` if it's dependent on the return of an async function or the field is dynamic. Use `defaultValues` if the fields are static.

You should never use `setValue` for updating a field array. This could cause problems in rerendering components. Just put it from values.

```
values: asynFn ? { ...asyncFn } : defaultValues
```